# Customizing SharePoint 2013 calendar day names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint, calendar

I am currently getting into a Sharepoint project, but have no prior Sharepoint experience. I have to change the default length of displayed day names in SharePoint 2013 Calendar.

[image]

I need Mon instead of Monday, Tue instead of Tuesday etc.

I found the following solution: http://sharepointom.blogspot.com/2017/07/change-calendar-days-name-to-short-3.html

The problem is, that it will not work when I change the month. AJAX call is being made and new date from new month comes, changing back to long days names.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpliest solution for this problem using CSS. Other javascript answers are correct as well.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
    /* calendar */
    .ms-acal-month-top span {
        display: none;
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(2)::after  {
        content: 'MON';
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(3)::after  {
        content: 'TUE';
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(4)::after  {
        content: 'WED';
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(5)::after  {
        content: 'THU';
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(6)::after  {
        content: 'FRI';
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(7)::after  {
        content: 'SAT';
    }
    .ms-acal-month-top:nth-of-type(8)::after  {
        content: 'SUN';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the ajax loaded event, here is how you can:

```
// execute the script only when the calendar JS file loads 
LoadSodByKey("SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js", function () {
    WaitForCalendarToLoad();
});


function WaitForCalendarToLoad() {
 // running your function for the first time IF YOU NEED TO!
    your_function();


    var _onItemsSucceed = 
     SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed; 
     SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed = 
       function($p0, $p1) { 
            _onItemsSucceed.call(this, $p0, $p1);

        // now let it call your function each time the calendar is loaded
       your_function();
    }
}
```

Replace your_function() with your current method and it should be fine.

From https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/828440cc-e822-4af3-b500-10031e2ee0a7/change-calendar-web-part-days-name?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below into a script editor web part in the calendar view page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//execute the script only when the calendar JS file loads 
LoadSodByKey("SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js", function () {
    WaitForCalendarToLoad();
});
function WaitForCalendarToLoad() {
    //running your function for the first time IF YOU NEED TO!
    ChangeDaysName();
    var _onItemsSucceed = 
     SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed; 
     SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed = 
       function($p0, $p1) { 
            _onItemsSucceed.call(this, $p0, $p1);
        //now let it call your function each time the calendar is loaded
       ChangeDaysName();
    }
}
function ChangeDaysName(){
    $("table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > th.ms-acal-month-top").each(function(){
        //get the first 3 chars from day name
        $cell = $(this).text().substring(0,3);
        $(this).text($cell);

   });
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This works well, but I found a simplier solution with CSS. Btw. do you know how I can adjust this view to display weekly for mobile decives?

Comment: Check site provisioning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/branding-and-site-provisioning-solutions-for-sharepoint